# What is the relative acceleration of a ball thrown inside a bus with respect to a man sitting inside if bus has uniform velocity?

Tags: kinematics, relative-motion

Like both man and ball are experiencing acceleration due to gravity so will the ball have no acceleration w.r.t to man?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The man also has a force from the reaction force from the seat he is sitting In, the man in an ideal world has zero acceleration , the relative acceleration is therefore -g m/s^2

Comment: Did you never drop something in a bus or a train: Why do you think there is difference in the bus compared to moving with the earth rotation or consider the earth a bus going around the sun with speed more than 1000km/h